# Reinstate lost leading zeroes in Python list

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a list of geographical postcodes that take the format `xxxx` (a string of numbers).

However, in the process of gathering and treating the data, the leading zero has been lost in cases where the postcode begins with `'0'`.

I need to reinstate the leading `'0'` in such cases.

Postcodes either occur singularly as `xxxx`, or they occur as a range in my list, `xxxx-xxxx`.

Have:

```
v = ['821-322', '877', '2004-2218', '2022']
```

Desired output:

```
['0821-0322', '0877', '2004-2218', '2022']
  ^    ^       ^
```

Attempt:

```
for i in range(len(v)):
    v[i] = re.sub(pattern, '0' + pattern, v)
```

However, I'm struggling with the regex pattern, and how to simply get the desired result.
There is no requirement to use `re.sub()`.  Any simple solution will do.

Comment: Use f-strings instead: `f'{12:0>4}'` where the `12` is the variable that you want to pad the numbers of.

Comment: @HampusLarsson could you kindly post as an answer with an explanation?  I'm not following so well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use f-string formatting instead!

Here is a one-liner to solve your problem:

```
>>> v = ['821-322', '877', '2004-2218', '2022']
>>> ["-".join([f'{i:0>4}' for i in x.split("-")]) for x in v]
['0821-0322', '0877', '2004-2218', '2022']
```

A more verbose example is this:

```
v = ['821-322', '877', '2004-2218', '2022']
newv = []
for number in v:
    num_holder = []    
    # Split the numbers on "-", returns a list of one if no split occurs
    for num in number.split("-"):
        # Append the formatted string to num_holder
        num_holder.append(f'{num:0>4}')
    # After each number has been formatted correctly, create a
    # new string which is joined together with a "-" once again and append it to newv
    newv.append("-".join(num_holder))
print(newv)
```

You can read up more on how f-strings work [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) and a further description of the "mini-language" that is used by the formatter [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

The short version of the explanation is this:

`f'{num:0>4}'`

- `f` tells the interpreter that a format-string is following
- `{}` inside of the string tells the formatter that it is a replacement-field and should be "calculated"
- `num` inside of the brackets is a reference to a variable
- `:` tells the formatter that there is a format-specifier settings following.
- `0` is the variable / value that should be used to 'fill' the string.
- `>` is the alignment of the variable `num` on the new string. `>` means to the right.
- `4` is the minimum number of characters that we want the resulting string to have. If `num` is equal to or greater that `4` characters long then the formatter will do nothing.